# AlertDialog onDismiss not called by screen rotation

Tags: android, screen, android-alertdialog, screen-rotation

I have an AlerDialog and want to do some clean ups (releasing MediaPlayer e.g.). So I add an dismiss listener.

```
m_dialog.setOnCancelListener(new OnCancelListener()
{
    public void onCancel(DialogInterface arg0)
    {
        stop();
    }
});
m_dialog.setOnDismissListener(new OnDismissListener()
{
    public void onDismiss(DialogInterface dialog)
    {
        stop();
    }
});
```

This works fine when the back button is pressed. But when the screen rotates the dialog hides but is not reconstructed AND onDimiss was not called before.

Any ideas, is this a bug in Android 2.3 ?

Answer (score 0):

Here is quick fix:

```
protected void onDestroy() {
    if(m_dialog.isShowing())
        m_dialog.dismiss();
    super.onDestroy();
}
```

Understand that this is what happens for you if you opened the Dialog with `Activity#showDialog()`. (I am guessing that you use `m_dialog.show()` instead, so really my advice is to use `showDialog()` or upgrade to Fragments.)

Comment: Hello,thanks but I use AlerDialog.Builder so  no possibility to override onDestroy. Fragments are not supported on older devices!

Comment: `onDestroy()` is a method in Activity and the [Support Library](http://developer.android.com/tools/extras/support-library.html) lets any device from Android 1.6 (API 4) onwards to use Fragments.

Comment: ok! But is this a bug or have I misunderstood something. I can also use a traditional Dialog, switching to fragments only for this is too much. But thanks

Comment: If you are using `m_dialog.show()` it is not a bug, this is just standard behavior. I agree that switching to Fragments is a lot of work, but using `Activity`'s `showDialog()` and overriding `onCreateDialog()` is quite simple.